# Conditions for a certain ideal in a ring of functions $R^X$ to be principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity. Let $X$ be a set, and let $Y\subset{X}$. The set ${R^{X}}$ which consists of all functions $X\rightarrow{R}$ is a ring under the binary operations $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x),$ and $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Let $I=\{f\in{R^{X}}:f(Y)=0\}$. Under what conditions on $Y$ is $I$ a principal ideal in $R^{X}$? One condition I found was $Y=X$. In this case $I=(0)$. I can't think of other conditions on $Y$ in this general setup that would enable us to conclude that $I$ is a principal ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $X \to R$ that vanish on a fixed subset $Y$ of $X$ always form a principal ideal for any set $X$ and any ring $R$. In fact, it is the principal ideal generated by the indicator function of the complement of $Y$.

Comment: By contrast, if $Y$ is infinite, and $I$ consists of functions that vanish at all but a finite number of points in $Y$, then $I$ is not a principal ideal. For let $S(f)$ be the set of points at which $f$ does not vanish. if any particular $f\in{I}$ generates $I$, then the ideal generated by $f$ fails to contain the indicator function of $\{a\}$ for any $a$ that does not belong to $S(f)$. This proves that $R^{X}$ is not a principal ideal domain, even if it happens to be an integral domain,

Comment: @student But actually, $R^X$ is never an integral domain if $X$ has more than one element, even if $R$ is one, for it contains nontrivial idempotents that take both 0 and 1 as values.